# Importing Access database of the accdb format in to SQL Server 2014 (Express edition)

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, import

I have a problem with importing my accdb database into SQL Server 2014. Please have a look at the following steps that I followed and let me know if I'm missing something.

Version of SQL Server I'm using: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (Intel X86), Express edition

Version of SQL Server Management Studio I'm using: SQL Server 2016 Management Studio, Community Technology Preview 3

Instructions to import data in to SSMS: in SQL Server Management Studio, connect to the database engine server type, expand databases, right-click a database, point to Tasks, and then click Import data or export data.

There was no option to import the accdb database , so I downloaded the following: Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable

I chose the 32 bit version. (I assume it is 32 bit - there are two options one is specified as the 64 bit , the other one isn't specified as anything, I chose the other one )

Back to the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

I still find no option for Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Thank you.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you restart SSMS after installing the "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable"? (or perhaps restart the computer?)

Comment: Thankyou @Andre , yes I have tried restarting SSMS as well as the PC and still do not get the option for importing the accdb format.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and here's what I did:

1. Export the data from access to a xls file
2. Click format and choose xls 97 - 2003
3. Use the same import method in SQL Server but choose Excel
4. Click browse and choose the file you exported from Access

This worked for me....may not be the perfect answer but will get your data imported

You may also try installing the Access Database Engine from Microsoft found [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)

Comment: The provided link is dead.